# EnablePasswordReset in Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-membership

I'd like to reset user password. I've a method like the following code. `EnablePasswordReset` does not overwrite because It's abstract. I've already changed web.config. But still take a error :

> Password reset is not enabled. Set the EnablePasswordReset property of
>   the membership provider to true.

How to `EnablePasswordReset` value set `true`?

```
  public static string ResetCurrentUserPassword(string userName)
  {
      MembershipProvider p = (MembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["Default"];
      //p.EnablePasswordReset value false;
      MembershipUser obj = Membership.GetUser(userName);

      return obj.ResetPassword();             
  }
```

web.config

```
        <siteMap defaultProvider="SitefinitySiteMap">
            <providers>
                <add name="SitefinitySiteMap" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinitySiteMap, Telerik.Sitefinity" enablePasswordReset="true" taxonomyProvider="OpenAccessDataProvider" pageTaxonomy="Pages" rootNode="FrontendSiteMap" pageProvider="OpenAccessDataProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
        <roleManager enabled="false"/>
        <membership defaultProvider="Default">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="Default" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.SitefinityMembershipProvider, Telerik.Sitefinity" enablePasswordReset="true"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in your `web.config` file;

```
enablePasswordReset="true"
```

Check out [*MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.enablepasswordreset.aspx) example;

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="SqlServices"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      passwordFormat="Hashed"
      applicationName="MyApplication" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

You said, you done it before, please check in your codebehind like this;

```
if (!Membership.EnablePasswordReset)
{

}
```

Check your membership is really using it or not.

Comment: I wrote a control like your said but EnablePasswordReset value still false. I changed web.config, It's above. But still same. I resetted web.config.

Comment: @baros Are you sure your membership system using `SitefinitySiteMap` provider?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, can take user's password. I use that.

Comment: I think, It's not standart membership, doesn't allow to reset Pasword

Comment: @baros Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918465/hashed-passwords-cannot-be-retrieved-either-set-the-password-format-to-differen